# SQL GroupBy to select % of values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, count, group-by

I'm using Access (I know JET SQL is different from T-SQL but if you have the answer in T-SQL I'll try to translate it) and I've got the following:

- Table Department with department name and id and other info
- Table Applications with a list of applications and whether or not they are deployable (boolean/bit)
- Table ApplicationMapping which link DepartmentId and ApplicationId (n:n relationship)

I'm trying to know for each department how many applications are deployable (easy) but also how many are not, and thus the % of completion. (or at least something like (count(where deployable = true)/count(*))

I really don't know how to make a query like that.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

*(This answer was developed and tested under Access 2010.)*

First we need a query giving you the total number of Applications by Department. Easy:

```sql
SELECT DepartmentId, Count(*) AS CountOfApplications
FROM ApplicationMapping
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

Say that gives us

```
DepartmentId  CountOfApplications
------------  -------------------
           1                    4
           2                    1
```

You already have the query to count Deployable Applications by Department, which probably looks something like this

```sql
SELECT 
    am.DepartmentId, 
    Sum(IIf(a.Deployable,1,0)) AS CountOfDeployable
FROM
    ApplicationMapping AS am
    INNER JOIN
    Applications AS a
        ON am.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

Let's assume that it gives us

```
DepartmentId  CountOfDeployable
------------  -----------------
           1                  2
           2                  1
```

Then all we need to do is JOIN those two queries together

```sql
SELECT 
    q1.DepartmentId,
    q2.CountOfDeployable / q1.CountOfApplications AS pctDeployable
FROM
    (
        SELECT DepartmentId, Count(*) AS CountOfApplications
        FROM ApplicationMapping
        GROUP BY DepartmentId
    ) AS q1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            am.DepartmentId, 
            Sum(IIf(a.Deployable,1,0)) AS CountOfDeployable
        FROM
            ApplicationMapping AS am
            INNER JOIN
            Applications AS a
                ON am.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
        GROUP BY DepartmentId
    ) AS q2
        ON q1.DepartmentId = q2.DepartmentId
```

and we get

```
DepartmentId  pctDeployable
------------  -------------
           1            0.5
           2              1
```

### Edit:

If you want a list that includes all Departments, even those without *any* Applications, then just wrap the whole preceding query in another query that does an outer join on the [Department] table:

```sql
SELECT
    d.DepartmentId,
    d.DepartmentName,
    IIf(IsNull(calc.DepartmentId),0,calc.CountOfApplications) AS totalApplications,
    calc.pctDeployable
FROM
    Department AS d
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            q1.DepartmentId,
            q1.CountOfApplications,
            q2.CountOfDeployable / q1.CountOfApplications AS pctDeployable
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DepartmentId, Count(*) AS CountOfApplications
                FROM ApplicationMapping
                GROUP BY DepartmentId
            ) AS q1
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    am.DepartmentId, 
                    Sum(IIf(a.Deployable,1,0)) AS CountOfDeployable
                FROM
                    ApplicationMapping AS am
                    INNER JOIN
                    Applications AS a
                        ON am.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
                GROUP BY DepartmentId
            ) AS q2
                ON q1.DepartmentId = q2.DepartmentId
    ) AS calc
        ON d.DepartmentId = calc.DepartmentId
```

returning

```
DepartmentId  DepartmentName  totalApplications  pctDeployable
------------  --------------  -----------------  -------------
           1  Department1                     4            0.5
           2  Department2                     1              0
           3  Department3                     0
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working except for departments having no deployable applications where there is no line. I added an join to the department table to have the department name instead of departmentid.

Comment: @user3031081 I have tweaked the queries to include Departments with no deployable Applications.

Comment: (or when there is no applications for this department so should be 1). Perhaps I should add a outer join to the department list

Comment: @user3031081 Yes, to include Departments with no Applications *at all* you will need to do an outer join on the [Department] table.

Comment: when I add the outer join, it says JOIN Expression not supported :/ Perhaps I need to do a subquery.

Comment: @user3031081 I have added another query to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use join in this case -

- following query should give you desired result, But in Oracle database.
  I am not sure how to translate into Access.

  ```
  SELECT department_id,
         total_cnt,
         (deployable_cnt / total_cnt) * 100 deployable_perc,
         100 - (deployable_cnt / total_cnt) * 100 not_deployable_perc
  FROM (SELECT dep.department_id,
               COUNT(*) total_cnt,
               SUM(CASE
                    WHEN app.deployable = 'Y' THEN
                    1
                    ELSE
                    0
                   END) deployable_cnt
         FROM department dep, applications app, applicationmapping appmap
        WHERE appmap.application_id = app.application_id
         and  appmap.department_id =  dep.department_id
   -- some other condition, if any
    GROUP BY dep.department_id)
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I think it should work on T-SQL but since we don't have CASE/WHEN in Access, it's not working :/ but I keep it !